# Are there any securities that pay out a fixed percentage of a company's profits?

Tags: stocks, dividends, reit

Are there securities where investors are always paid a specific percentage of the company's profits if profits have been made?

I know that some REITs are mandated to distribute minimum percentage of their profits as dividends. Are there any other securities that pay a fixed percentage of profits as dividends?

(original question, but low quality: [Some basic questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125282/some-basic-questions/125284))

Comment: They may exist but I have never come across a dividend based on profits.  There are some preferred stocks whose dividend is floating (tied to LIBOR) and I suppose, eventually to SOFR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for arbitrary corporations (meaning that companies cannot be "forced" to distribute their profits), but [Master Limited Partnerships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_limited_partnership) have a structure similar to what you're describing. They distribute most of their profits to unitholders in a way that's analogous to a dividend but with different tax treatment.

MLPs are limited to certain industries, and abut 2/3 of them are in the oil and gas midstream sector (gas pipelines/processing, oil transportation, etc.). They are typically companies that operate based on fixed fees, so they're not as exposed to fluctuations in commodity prices.

Comment: In Canada, "Income Trusts" serve a similar purpose as MLPs in the US.